# Docker cannot mount any folder under /var on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, macos-catalina

After I upgrade to the latest version of docker on Mac os 10.15.3. I get Mounts denied error again.

Here are the versions:

```
Docker desktop: 2.2.0.3(42716)
Engine: 19.03.5
Mac osx: Catalina(10.15.3)
Docker compose: 1.25.4
```

I try to mount `/var/data/test:/var/data/test` in the docker-compose file. And I choose the folder in the `File Sharing` menu, it turns out to be `/private/var/data/test` and can't edit anymore.

If I try to run `docker-compose up`, always get `Mounts denied` error.

```
ERROR: for c9430ce45017_xxx-SNAPSHOT  Cannot start service xxx: Mounts denied:
The path /var/data/test
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
```

**Update:**
As @tripleee suggest, I edit the compose file to `/private/var/data/test:/var/data/test`, it works. But it won't work on the server which is Linux.

Comment: What happens if you put in the real path under `/private` instead?

Comment: @tripleee do you mean in the compose file or in the sharing folder?

Comment: Probably both actually.

Comment: In Catalina, `/private` is [firmlinked to `/System/Volumes/Data/private`](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/11/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout-revised-for-10-15-release/), so if using `/private/var/data/test` doesn't work try `/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/data/test` instead. (And if you get it working, post an answer so that others facing the same problem can find your solution.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Unfortunately, I can't put the path `/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/data/test` in the docker desktop file sharing entries. It will be changed to `/private/var/data/test` automatically. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Thanks for @GordonDavisson sharing your two cents.*

Even I can't put the `/var/data/test` through the docker desktop GUI, I set the sharing file directories from the command line finally.

The shared folders list displayed in the GUI can also be edited in `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`.

If the user has already modified shared folders, the "filesharingDirectories" array will already exist in `settings.json`, you can just add the path in the json array. If not modified, the array is not present in `settings.json`, but you can add it with your path in addition to the default ones :

```
"filesharingDirectories" : [
    "/Users",
    "/Volumes",
    "/private",
    "/tmp", 
    "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder"
  ]
```

Eventually, the app needs restarting so that folders are visible in the VM.

Credits to this [link](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2214#issuecomment-395798225)

**At last, I put `/var/data/test` in the `settings.json`, after restarting the docker it works.**